# Electron 'contextBridge'

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, electron

To provide suitable levels of security when loading remote content, it is stated that a `BrowserWindow`'s `contextIsolation` and `nodeIntegration` options must be enabled and disabled respectively. In this scenario, Node/Electron APIs will not be available to the main renderer process. In order to expose specific functionality, the window's preload script may exploit Electron's `contextBridge` feature, providing the main renderer with access to selected Node/Electron APIs.

Despite information provided in the Electron docs, concrete examples of `contextBridge` usage are lacking overall. In general, existing documentation/tutorials do not focus on adopting secure practices when implementing an Electron app.

The following is a single `contextBridge` usage example I've managed to find online: https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template

Would you be able to provide additional resources/examples which might be useful for the implementation of a secure Electron app (which relies on the `contextBridge` functionality)?

Insight regarding `contextBridge` best practices is also highly appreciated.

Comment: example in electron docs https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/context-bridge#api-objects is quite straightforward to follow, then enabling ctxisolation / disabling nodeintegration would do trick. Specific part you are encountering problem you'd like to have example references not provided by docs?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure contextBridge is going to be particularly useful in my case. I also need to send dynamic values via IPC. It seems that this is not possible using contextBridge, as values are hardcoded within the preload script. So, I'm not sure which would be the best way to go about this. @OJKwon

Comment: It should be helpful providing code what `dynamic` means. Ctxbridge is not for usefulness, it's supportive interface to help more secure electron applications.

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand why is `sendEvent: (event) => ipcRenderer.send(event)` less secure than `doAThing: () => ipcRenderer.send('doAThing')`.

Answer (score 16):

I'm the author of the template, let me offer some background knowledge you might find helpful. *Disclaimer*: I'm not a security researcher, but this is scraped from multiple sources.

[ContextBridge](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/context-bridge) is important because it offers **protection** against passing values into the renderer process based off the *old way*.

**Old way**

```js
const {
    ipcRenderer
} = require("electron");

window.send = function(channel, data){
    // whitelist channels
    let validChannels = ["toMain"];
    if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
        ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
    }
};

window.recieve = function(channel, func){
    let validChannels = ["fromMain"];
    if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
        // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender` 
        ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args));
    }
};
```

This code is vulnerable to the client opening the dev tools, and modifying the function definition of `window.send` and `window.recieve`. The client can then start to ping your ipcMain in your **main.js** script and then possibly do some damage because they could get around your whitelisting ipc channels in the preload js. This assumes you are whitelisting in your main.js too, but I've seen *plenty* of examples that are not and would be vulnerable to such an attack.

From [the docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/context-bridge#api-objects):

> Function values are proxied to the other context and all other values are copied and frozen. Any data / primitives sent in the API object become immutable and updates on either side of the bridge do not result in an update on the other side.

In other words, because we use `contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld`, our renderer process cannot modify the definition of the functions we expose, protecting us from a possible security attack vector.

**New way**

```js
const {
    contextBridge,
    ipcRenderer
} = require("electron");

// Expose protected methods that allow the renderer process to use
// the ipcRenderer without exposing the entire object
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    "api", {
        send: (channel, data) => {
            // whitelist channels
            let validChannels = ["toMain"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
            }
        },
        receive: (channel, func) => {
            let validChannels = ["fromMain"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender` 
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args));
            }
        }
    }
);
```

[Source](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template/blob/master/docs/newtoelectron.md)

Comment: How is this a security risk if the client is running code on their local machine?

Comment: If your code loads/uses remote content, there is a risk the remote content could be malicious and infect/cause some damage to your local machine. If you are using all local code, then it should be safe. NOTE - if you are using NPM there is always some caution you should have in dependencies your app has/is using.

Comment: thanks for authoring this template....can you speak on accessing window.[foo] from a React app. I keep getting `window.ipcrenderer` is not a function. Clearly, this is an import issue.

Comment: @ChrisC You are welcome. I'm not exactly sure with your code base, but `window.api.send/receive` are available, _not_ `window.ipcrenderer`, with the above example.

Comment: Welp, whenever I expose in my react app, window.electron is always undefined

Comment: Technically allowing the electron rendered access to the nodejs is basically the same as running an SSH shell but with a fancy UI. Security wise, they would have to be treated the same. I can see how locking down the renderer is like defense in depth or principle of least privilege, but it does make it harder to program certain applications.

Answer (score 11):

Here are `all` the steps to set this up

1. In your main electron `index.js` file, point to the preload script in your `BrowserWindow` config object:

```js
new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    preload: path.resolve(app.getAppPath(), 'preload.js')
  }
})
```

2. The `preload.js` needs to be in your app folder. I use webpack to compile everything, so the `preload.js` file is not where my js code is, it's in the app directory where `electron-builder` will compile the executable. Here's what the `preload.js` contains:

```js
process.once('loaded', () => {
  const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer, shell } = require('electron')
  
  contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
    on (eventName, callback) {
      ipcRenderer.on(eventName, callback)
    },

    async invoke (eventName, ...params) {
      return await ipcRenderer.invoke(eventName, ...params)
    },

    async shellOpenExternal (url) {
      await shell.openExternal(url)
    },

    async shellOpenPath (file) {
      await shell.openPath(file)
    },

    async shellTrashItem (file) {
      await shell.trashItem(file)
    }
  })
})
```

3. All this is part of the node.js code. Now let's see how we use this code in our renderer code, the chrome client side code.

```js
window.electron.on('nodeJSEvent', (event, param1, param2) => {
  console.log('nodeJSEvent has been called with params', param1, param2)
})

const foo = await window.electron.invoke('nodeJSEvent', param1, param2)
console.log(foo)

await window.electron.shellOpenExternal(url)

await window.electron.shellOpenPath(file)

await window.electron.shellTrashItem(file)
```

That's it. All this code is about giving the possibility to the client side code to call nodejs code that we define in the preload script.

Comment: you are awesome, whole day i am looking for this

Comment: Exposing these methods to the renderer just makes it unsafe again and defeats the purpose. This is not secure whatsoever!

Comment: @assembly_wizard This is what the electron docs suggests https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/context-bridge#exposing-node-global-symbols What exactly is the alternative here?

Comment: @dreamLo These docs show an example of exposing a simple hash function. They also exclaim "Be very cautious about which globals and APIs you expose", and exposing all of these Electron methods is very unsafe. For example, you're giving the renderer free reign over your filesystem with openPath and trashItem.

Comment: @assembly_wizard It depends on what kind of application you're developing. For example I'm working on an application that is a file manager, so it's expected to give file access to the user.

Comment: @dreamLo You're right, but I fear developers copying this code and thinking you just need to proxy functions, while actually you need to treat it as a client-server scenario and not trust the client

Comment: @dreamLo Yes, by all means give the user file access via your main thread, but only by pre-defined and vetted paths, not any path submitted (or hacked) by a user in the render thread **direct** to the main thread. EG: `window.electron.shellTrashItem(%SystemRoot%)` would be bad.

Comment: @midnight-coding It depends on what you're building. I'm building a file manager which prompts the user to pick a folder that he wishes to manage. This means that once you picked that folder, you are able to create, rename, delete any file in that folder the user has chosen. Forbidding access to certain files, should not be a concern of the application, but of the operating system. If the current user has access to certain files, then by all means edit them. Otherwise, the OS will complain that the user doesn't have access to /etc/hosts

Comment: @dreamLo To true, it depends on what you are building. The OS will definitely complain if you are not an administrator and you try and edit the `/etc/hosts` file. On the other hand, a number of years ago I had a computer that was on the way out. Just before I powered it down for the last time (prior to upgrade its hardware and software) I did a 'Select All' of the `C;/` drive and pressed delete. To my surprise, it got a fair way into the delete before it complained.

Answer (score 3):

I had some trouble with this myself. My solution was this preload.js template

```
const { ipcRenderer, contextBridge } = require('electron')

const validChannels = ["toMain", "myRenderChannel"];

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
  "api", {
    send: (channel, data) => {
        if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
            ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
        }
    },
    on: (channel, callback) => {
      if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
        // Filtering the event param from ipcRenderer
        const newCallback = (_, data) => callback(data);
        ipcRenderer.on(channel, newCallback);
      }
    },
    once: (channel, callback) => { 
      if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
        const newCallback = (_, data) => callback(data);
        ipcRenderer.once(channel, newCallback);
      }
    },
    removeListener: (channel, callback) => {
      if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
        ipcRenderer.removeListener(channel, callback);
      }
    },
    removeAllListeners: (channel) => {
      if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
        ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners(channel)
      }
    },
  }
);
```

Comment: the `remove` method would not work. because the callback between preload and renderer is not the same memory one.