# ipcRenderer.on is not a function

Tags: electron

I am using the **`Main`** › **`Preload`** › **`Renderer`** process stack.

## `preload.js`

```js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('ipcRenderer', ipcRenderer)
```

## `renderer.js`

```js
console.log(ipcRenderer) // it shows something like:
/**
{_events: {…}, _eventsCount: 0, _maxListeners: undefined, send: ƒ, sendSync: ƒ, …}
invoke: ƒ ()
postMessage: ƒ ()
send: ƒ ()
sendSync: ƒ ()
sendTo: ƒ ()
sendToHost: ƒ ()
Symbol(kCapture): false
_events: {}
_eventsCount: 0
_maxListeners: undefined
__proto__: Object
**/

console.log(ipcRenderer.on) // undefined
```

When trying to use the [`ipcRenderer.on()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendereronchannel-listener) method, it is logging an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: ipcRenderer.on is not a function
```

Was this method been removed in the newer versions? What is causing it to be not available on the renderer process?

Comment: `contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('ipcRenderer', ipcRenderer)` -> very bad idea!

Comment: Yes I know the security holes of that. I am just showing that here for brevity, to easily understand the flow.

Comment: Have you tried `window.ipcRenderer.on()`

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya `window.ipcRenderer.on()` still logs the same error

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59993468/electron-contextbridge . Instead of exposing the entire `ipcRenderer` completely, try a specific function.

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya Thanks for that find. Using that link, what I found was that `ipcRenderer.on()` method is available inside the **preload** process but will not be available to the **renderer** process when the `ipcRenderer` object was passed via the `contextBridge`. A bit weird for programmers' intuition but great for security purposes.

Comment: @AbelCallejo that comment actually answers your question, would be very useful to move to a separate answer

Answer (score 6):

Here's a little workaround for that. Yet i don't think this is a good idea for security.

```js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");    
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("electron", { ipcRenderer: { ...ipcRenderer, on: ipcRenderer.on } });
```

Answer (score 4):

As the Electron API documentation for [ipcRenderer](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer) states, "The `ipcRenderer` module is an [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter)".

This "EventEmitter" referenced by Electron is the EventEmitter class of node.js. Electron's `ipcRenderer`  module **inherits** node's EventEmitter class.

The methods viewable by `console.log(ipcRenderer)` are **Electron's** methods. All inherited methods are found in the Prototype object, which is exactly where you will find the `on()` method.

To see this in action add `console.log(ipcRenderer)` to a typical, well formed, safe and readable `preload.js` script.

`preload.js` (main thread)

```js
// Import the necessary Electron components.
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// White-listed channels.
const ipc = {
    'render': {
        // From render to main.
        'send': [],
        // From main to render.
        'receive': [],
        // From render to main and back again.
        'sendReceive': []
    }
};

// Exposed protected methods in the render process.
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods.
    'ipcRender', {
        // From render to main.
        send: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.send;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
            }
        },
        // From main to render.
        receive: (channel, listener) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.receive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {

                // Show me the prototype (use DevTools in the render thread)
                console.log(ipcRenderer);

                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`.
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => listener(...args));
            }
        },
        // From render to main and back again.
        invoke: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.sendReceive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, args);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Now, open Chrome's DevTools and view the Console tab.

`Chrome DevTools - Console Tab Output` (render thread)

```js
v EventEmitter
  > invoke: async ƒ (e,...t)
  > postMessage: ƒ (e,t,n)
  > send: ƒ (e,...t)
  > sendSync: ƒ (e,...t)
  > sendTo: ƒ (e,t,...n)
  > sendToHost: ƒ (e,...t)
  > _events: {app:versions: ƒ}
    _eventsCount: 1
    _maxListeners: undefined
    Symbol(kCapture): false
  v [[Prototype]]: Object
    > addListener: ƒ addListener(type, listener)
    > emit: ƒ emit(type, ...args)
    > eventNames: ƒ eventNames()
    > getMaxListeners: ƒ getMaxListeners()
    > listenerCount: ƒ listenerCount(type)
    > listeners: ƒ listeners(type)
    > off: ƒ removeListener(type, listener)
    v on: ƒ addListener(type, listener)        // <-- Here it is
        length: 2
        name: "addListener"
      > prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
        arguments: (...)
        caller: (...)
        [[FunctionLocation]]: VM14 node:events:486
        [[Prototype]]: ƒ ()
        [[Scopes]]: Scopes[2]
    > once: ƒ once(type, listener)
    > prependListener: ƒ prependListener(type, listener)
    > prependOnceListener: ƒ prependOnceListener(type, listener)
    > rawListeners: ƒ rawListeners(type)
    > removeAllListeners: ƒ removeAllListeners(type)
    > removeListener: ƒ removeListener(type, listener)
    > setMaxListeners: ƒ setMaxListeners(n)
      _events: undefined
      _eventsCount: 0
      _maxListeners: undefined
    > constructor: ƒ EventEmitter(opts)
      Symbol(kCapture): false
    > [[Prototype]]: Object
```

Answer (score 2):

this is a nice way to resolver this problem.

```js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("electron", {
  ipcRenderer: {
    ...ipcRenderer,
    on: ipcRenderer.on.bind(ipcRenderer),
    removeListener: ipcRenderer.removeListener.bind(ipcRenderer),
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little workaround for that.

```js
// preload.ts
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('_Electron_Event_Listener_', {
    onCreateBrowserView,
})

function onCreateBrowserView(listener: (event: IpcRendererEvent, ...args: any[]) => void) {
    ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners('/browserView/create')
    ipcRenderer.on('/browserView/create', listener)
}
```