Not able to fetch data from sqlite using ipcRenderer
I've started electron project using ionic. But stuck in one point where I need to fetch the data from the sqlite database.
I've getting data from API and saving it to the database.sqlite is working properly, but the issue is when I'm fetching it from database.sqlite using ipcRenderer is give me an error. "ERROR TypeError: me.on is not a function"
Here is the code
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: true,
        }
    })

const { ipcMain } = require('electron');
ipcMain.on('getMenus', (event, data) => {
    db.all(`SELECT * FROM menus`, [], (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
            event.reply('menusError', err.message);
        } else {
            event.reply('menus', rows);
        }
    });
});

Also saving data to same table 'menus'
In 'preload.js'
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
    ipcRenderer: ipcRenderer,
});

In 'ipc.service.ts'
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { IpcRendererEvent } from 'electron';

declare global {
    interface CustomIpcRenderer {
        send(channel: string, data: any): void;
        on(channel: string, listener: (event: IpcRendererEvent, ...args: any[]) => void): this;
    }

    interface Window {
        electron: {
            onRetrieveDataResponse(arg0: (event: any, response: any) => void): unknown;
            retrieveData(key: string): unknown;
            storeData(arg0: { key: string; value: string; }): unknown;
            onStoreDataResponse(arg0: (event: any, response: any) => void): unknown;
            ipcRenderer: {
                send: (channel: string, data: any) => void;
                on: (channel: string, func: (...args: any[]) => void) => void;
            };
        };
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class IpcService {
    private _ipc: CustomIpcRenderer | undefined = void 0;

    constructor() {
        if (window['electron']) {
            try {
                this._ipc = window['electron'].ipcRenderer as CustomIpcRenderer;
            } catch (e) {
                throw e;
            }
        } else {
            console.warn('Electron\'s IPC was not loaded');
        }
    }

    public on(channel: string, listener: (event: any, ...args: any[]) => void): void {
        console.log(`Setting up listener for channel: ${channel}`);
        this._ipc?.on(channel, listener);
    }

    public send(channel: string, data: any): void {
        if (!this._ipc) {
            return;
        }
        this._ipc?.send(channel, data);
    }
}

Fetching it in 'ngOnInit()'
this.ipcService.send('getMenus', null);

this.ipcService.on('menus', (event: any, rows: any) => {
   console.log('Received menus:', rows);
});

this.ipcService.on('menusError', (event: any, error: any) => {
   console.error('Error fetching menus:', error);
});

One

Two

Three

Four

Five

Please don't provide any kind of link I've searched everything.
I tried using ipcRenderer.

That the app is minified doesn't help, consider disabling the minifier. It's unclear at which point the error occurs. The entries of call stack can be clicked, currently only you can do this

@EstusFlask not getting your point.

You need to disable the minifier to get meaningful names instead of "me." and "ce.".You need to click on black links in the error to see where the error occurs. Nobody but you can do this. The question lacks a way to reproduce the error or debugging details, which is a requirement for a question on SO. From the code you posted it looks like this._ipc?.on() causes the error but I don't see how this could happen

@EstusFlask Screenshots added.

I see. It's a known problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66913598/ipcrenderer-on-is-not-a-function and https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/34471#issuecomment-1149729233
