# How to switch from remote to ipcMain and ipcRenderer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I am making electron app with react and I have titlebar controls done with remote module but in console I am getting warning that `remote` module is deprecated. I want to change my code to use `ipcMain` and `ipcRenderer` instead remote but I can't get it working.

This is my code that is working 100% atm but with remote module. Can someone show on at least one function for example `app.minimize()` how to use `ipcMain` and `ipcRenderer`?

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { remote } from "electron";
import {
  VscChromeMinimize,
  VscChromeMaximize,
  VscChromeRestore,
  VscChromeClose,
} from "react-icons/vsc";

const TitlebarControls = ({ minimize, maximize, close }) => {
  const app = remote.getCurrentWindow();
  const [maximizeIcon, setMaximizeIcon] = useState(
    app.isMaximized() ? <VscChromeRestore /> : <VscChromeMaximize />
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    app.on("maximize", () => setMaximizeIcon(<VscChromeRestore />));
    app.on("unmaximize", () => setMaximizeIcon(<VscChromeMaximize />));
  }, [app]);

  return (
    <ul className="titlebar-controls">
      {minimize && (
        <li className="minimize" onClick={() => app.minimize()}>
          <VscChromeMinimize />
        </li>
      )}
      {maximize && (
        <li
          className="maximize"
          onClick={() =>
            !app.isMaximized() ? app.maximize() : app.unmaximize()
          }
        >
          {maximizeIcon}
        </li>
      )}
      {close && (
        <li className="close" onClick={() => app.close()}>
          <VscChromeClose />
        </li>
      )}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default TitlebarControls;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `remote` module will be removed in Electron 14 but instead you can use `@electron/remote` module if you only care about deprecation. The [docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/breaking-changes#deprecated-remote-module) give the following way to use it:

```
// Deprecated way
// const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron').remote
// Replace with:
const { BrowserWindow } = require('@electron/remote')

// In the main process:
require('@electron/remote/main').initialize()
```

If you want the ipc method to achieve the same, do the following:

In renderer.js:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
//to minimize
ipcRenderer.send('minimize', data);//data contains any extra info you may need to send
```

In main.js:

```
const { ipcMain, app } = require('electron')
ipcMain.on('minimize', (event, data) => {
    //Minimize logic
})
```

Comment: This will not work unless `contextIsolation` is set to `false` and `nodeIntegration` is set to `true` when initializing the window, since their default values changed in electron `12.0.0`. Also it is advised to use a preload script with `contextBridge` since that improves security: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63894861/13752696

Comment: In my case is `renderer.js` my `TitlebarControls.js` file and `main.js` my `App.js` in src folder of React? Because i tryed that and didn't work. I have my `contextIsolation` set to `false` and `nodeIntegration` set to `true` because my remote didn't work without that.

Comment: @Foxeread is correct in that it does has an impact on security, but did this solution work for you @Klak031?

Comment: @akshayks not really, but probably because I am not sure what `renderer.js` and `main.js` refer to. Is `main.js` my `App.js` file from react or my `main.js` file from electron, and what is `renderer.js`

Comment: @Klak031 renderer.js typically refers to the file where you are handling dom events. Any file from which you want to send an ipc event would suffice. But it is generally a part of your frontend. main.js would be the file where you initialized the window for your app. You can also put it in any other file but for simplicity you can put it there.