# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined in Electron BrowserWindow

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am new to `electron js` and I am trying to use `devtron`. When I use `require` in the Electron Browser Window. I face this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Please note that I am getting this error when using require in BrowserWindow, not in the code. I have also tried setting `nodeIntegration: true,` and `contextIsolation: true` in `webPreferences`. I have attached the screenshot.

[image]

Here is my code of main.js

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
require('electron-reload')(__dirname);



function createWindow () {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1000,
    height: 700,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: true
    }
  })
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
 }

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
  app.on('activate', function () {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to use Node.js APIs in renderer process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66455289/unable-to-use-node-js-apis-in-renderer-process)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`contextIsolation` is enabled, disable `contextIsolation` and `nodeIntegration` should work.

```js
webPreferences: {
  nodeIntegration: true,
  contextIsolation: false
}
```

Comment: However, for security it is recommended to use `contextIsolation` instead of `nodeIntegration`. `nodeIntegration` exposes the whole node API to the renderer, which is potentially dangerous. Make sure to enable `nodeIntegration` only on windows that will load trusted, non-external content.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain both these things? or share any link from where I can get an idea about these?

Comment: `nodeIntegration` lets you use `require()` in the renderer process, if you load an external page, such as example.com, with `nodeIntegration` enabled in that window, the web page could use require, allowing it to access the filesystem API `const fs = require('fs')` and other node APIs. This can usually be prevented by not loading external pages, but it is still better to use `contextIsolation` because it permits you to select what APIs/functions can the renderer process execute. Here's an example of how to implement `contextIsolation`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59993468